# cURL Response JSON RestAPI

Tags: json, rest, curl, business-process-management

I need to delete some wrong data, inserted in a lot of processes, and I need to figure if this is possible with cURL and rest API, with a script in sh, batch or something like this:

```
curl -u admin:admin -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://json_bpm.com/wle/v1/service/6112449?action=getData&fields=context"
```

First I just need the result map.

Output:

```
{"status":"200","data":{"result":"{\"context\":{\"name\":\"xxx\" (...)
"resultMap":{"context":{"name\":"xxx\" (...) }}}
```

Because I need to remove the `userDelete` array (see below) for thousands of processes, and *set* this again using curl. If you know how to remove arrays from JSON too, you're the man. :)

```
 {
    "context": {
        "name": "Change Process",
        "startUser": {
            "user": "0001"
        },
        "endUser": {
            "user": "0001"
        },
        "userDelete": {
            "user": "0002"
        },
        "origin": "GUI",
        "userAction": "Change Process"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing json with sed and awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505)

Comment: well, is not the same thing, I just need to get the result without '\', and I couldn't perform this in unix because chars like ã, for example, I tried iconv to solve this, but the result...